# Columns not getting displayed in GridLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am trying to display a grid of buttons using gridLayout at runtime. I am trying to fit the gridLayout to fit the entire screen's width. I am able to do that for 3x3 and 5x5 button grid (using my nexus 4). But when I go for 7x7, I lose the last column of buttons i.e the last column of GridLayout. I seriously cant understand whats going wrong here.

Here's what I am doing.. I take the grid size from settings activity  and this is the number of columns in GridLayout (numColumns). I use LayoutParams and get the width and height and set the buttons' width and height to (layoutWidth/numColumns) and (layoutHeight/numColumns). Please help me here guyz.. I have pasted the code below.

```
public class StartGameActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_game);




    SharedPreferences sharedPref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int numColumns=Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("Grid", "3").toString());
    // create a RelativeLayout
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    //LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    // define the RelativeLayout layout parameters.
    //LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutparams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    DisplayMetrics metrics=new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int width=metrics.widthPixels;
    int height=metrics.heightPixels;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);


    GridLayout gridLayout=new GridLayout(this);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams gridLayoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();   
    gridLayoutParams.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);


    gridLayout.setColumnCount(numColumns);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(numColumns);
    gridLayout.setMinimumHeight(height);
    gridLayout.setMinimumWidth(width);

    for(int i=0;i<numColumns*numColumns;i++)
    {


        Button button=new Button(this);
        button.setWidth(width/numColumns);
        button.setHeight(width/numColumns);
        button.setMinWidth(width/numColumns);
        button.setMinHeight(width/numColumns);
        button.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
        //buttonForEveryRow++;
        //columIndex++;
        gridLayout.addView(button);
    }


    relativeLayout.addView(gridLayout,relativeLayoutParams1);
    setContentView(relativeLayout,relativeLayoutParams);



}
```

}

Comment: You have not considered the padding/spacing being added by Android by default in your width calculation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455495/gridlayoutnot-gridview-spaces-between-the-cells. I tried it but didn't work for me.

Comment: Hey @faizal.. Thanks for your reply..It doesnt work for me too..Its still showing the same

Comment: Inside your for loop, add the following lines at the end(after the  addView line) : ViewGroup.LayoutParams par = button.getLayoutParams();
        par.width=width/numColumns;
        par.height=width/numColumns;
        button.setLayoutParams(par);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the parameters of the button only after it has been added to it's parent layout.

So inside your FOR loop, remove all the `button.set..` lines and add the following lines at the end(after the gridLayout.addView line) :

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams par = button.getLayoutParams(); 
par.width=width/numColumns; 
par.height=width/numColumns; 
button.setLayoutParams(par);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams%28%29 :

*All views should have layout parameters. These supply parameters to the parent of this view specifying how it should be arranged.*