# Android: GridLayout spacing between items

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have a grid layout which is filled with buttons. I want the buttons to be more distant from each other, what code should I write? I tried to search for it but only found a solution for `GridView`, not `GridLayout`.

Comment: check this answer if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/21456391/1320616

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridLayout(not GridView) - Spaces between the cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455495/gridlayoutnot-gridview-spaces-between-the-cells)

Comment: These don't seem to be duplicates. This is about adding spacing; the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270404/android-gridlayout-spacing-between-items) is about removing it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can put margin to the buttons

Comment: what if I have to dynamically rearrange columns and rows? the margin will mess everything up in that case.

Comment: margin will not show equal spacing on each side. For example: margin of 2dp on each item will show 2 dp on each side but item after will also have 2 dp on each side. Making it total of 4dp space in between now.

Comment: You can put only margin end on the individual items to avoid duplication of margins.

Answer (score 28):

Instead of adding margin to each buttons, use `android:useDefaultMargins="true"`

It is better than adding margin to each buttons!

Comment: this doesn't answer the main question. Does this answer my doubts on the first answer? In that case you should've commented the answer.

Comment: Even if you re-arrange items they will stay distinct and wont mess up with each other